# WordPress text field in array problem

Tags: posts, wp-query, array

This my code.

```
    $idsposts  = solstice_get_opt('slider_4'); // example: 443,755,155,282
    $myposts  = array($idsposts); // must be array(443,755,155,282) but i saw array(443)

  $blog_featured_post_args = array(
    'post__in'            => $myposts,
    'orderby'             => 'ID',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    'post_type'           => 'post',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
  );
```

What is my problem? This code get only 1 post (in example showing only 443 id post)

(sorry for my english)

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump( $myposts )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be creating an array around a single long string that needs to be split up into array elements (assuming $idsposts is a string and not an array). Try using

```
$myposts = explode(",", $idsposts);
```

Instead of just adding $idsposts as the only element of your $myposts array.

You can also check if something is an array already using is_array($idsposts).